# Cache access issue while installing preproduction on symfony

Tags: php, caching, symfony, require

I am currently trying to install a preproduction branch on my dedicated serveur.

I installed a Symfony version in the `/web/preprod` directoty of my symfony production project. I managed to link correctly the front controller and the routes, and now I am calling an action in the preprod branch.

I am getting this error message :

> Warning:
>   require_once(/var/www/vhosts/ns21206.ovh.net/citydom/web/preprod/app/cache/prod_new/jms_diextra/proxies/CityDom-APIBundle-Controller-GangController.php):
>   failed to open stream: No such file or directory in
>   /var/www/vhosts/ns21206.ovh.net/citydom/web/preprod/app/cache/prod/jms_diextra/controller_injectors/CityDomAPIBundleControllerGangController.php
>   on line 13
>
> Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required '/var/www/vhosts/ns21206.ovh.net/citydom/web/preprod/app/cache/prod_new/jms_diextra/proxies/CityDom-APIBundle-Controller-GangController.php'
>   (include_path='.:/usr/share/pear:/usr/share/php') in
>   /var/www/vhosts/ns21206.ovh.net/citydom/web/preprod/app/cache/prod/jms_diextra/controller_injectors/CityDomAPIBundleControllerGangController.php
>   on line 13

The preprod cache folders are on permission 777.

Not all action aren't working, but this one doesn't.

Comment: why don't you clear the cache and try again

Comment: Same after cleaning the preprod cache

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See *Setting up Permissions* in [this section](http://symfony.com/doc/master/book/installation.html#configuration-and-setup). Go with the `setfacl` command.

Comment: I have set the permissions :
`setfacl -R -m u:root:rwX -m u:whoami:rwX app/cache app/logs
setfacl -dR -m u:root:rwx -m u:whoami:rwx app/cache app/logs`

But the error message is still the same

Comment: I finally managed to get rid of this error. I manually modified the access permission to the cache files, it worked after a few times.

Thanks ;)